# Simple Sencha 2.0 mvc list

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to write my first simple mvc app. I have a Main View and a Products view. I also have a Main controller. My Products view extend Ext.List. My problem is the list doesn't show anything even though I've set the data and itemTpl. Here is my code:

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'SenchaTest',


    controllers: ['Main'],


    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        Ext.create('SenchaTest.view.Main');
    },
});
```

view/Main.js

```
Ext.define('SenchaTest.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    requires:['Ext.data.Store'],

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'productspage',
                title:'Products',
                data: [
                        { title: 'Item 1' },
                        { title: 'Item 2' },
                        { title: 'Item 3' },
                        { title: 'Item 4' }
                ],
                itemTpl:'{title}'
            }
        ]
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Main view initialize');
    }

});
```

view/Products.js

```
Ext.define('SenchaTest.view.Products', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'productspage',

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Products view initialize');
    },

});
```

controller/Main.js

```
Ext.define('SenchaTest.controller.Main',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config:{
        views:['Main', 'Products'],
    },

    launch: function() {
        console.log('Main Controller launch');
    },

    init: function() {
        console.log('Main Controller init');
    }
});
```

Here is what appears in my console:

```
Main Controller init 
Products view initialize 
Main view initialize 
Main Controller launch
```

So my views and controller are initiated. But nothing shows in my products list. The list component does seem to have been loaded because i can see scrollbars when dragging it.

**The weird thing is if I change the xtype: 'productspage' to xtype:'list' .... it works .... but my products view extend Ext.List ... so isn't it the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue .. omg this was all because of the initialize override of the view Products.js not calling the base method ...

Comment: Hi, can you be a little more descriptive ?? What exactly did you do to get rid of this error ? Cos I am getting the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a layout to your main view

```
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout:'fit', <---------- the item is gonna fit the screen
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'productspage',
            title:'Products',
            data: [
                    { title: 'Item 1' },
                    { title: 'Item 2' },
                    { title: 'Item 3' },
                    { title: 'Item 4' }
            ],
            itemTpl:'{title}'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, it'd be great if you could make a Senchafiddle, then it'd be much easier to help you.

Comment: Also, try to inspect the DOM to see if the list is there but with a 0px height, or if it's not even there at all.

Comment: inspecting the dom seems to show the list is there with width and height to 100%.

Comment: I tried SenchaFiddle, I can't seem to make it work. It doesn't look like behaving the same as on my machine. I'll try to make it work with senchafiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try putting all of your configs (title, data, itemTpl) in your `productsPage` definition.

Comment: yup tried that too. It's really bizarre. The weird thing is xtype:'list', it works, but when i switch to productspage no data is showns. But the list component is loaded with no data. When i extend the productspage to a simple panel and have html in the config. It does show the html. So all points the everything is setup right but just no data ....

Comment: "The weird thing is xtype:'list', it works, but when i switch to productspage no data is showns. But the list component is loaded with no data"? I don't understand this

Comment: yeah it looks like when xtype:'productspage', the list component is shown but no data. I can see a scrollbar when trying to scroll the list. But when I only change xtype:'list' instead of xtype:'productspage', data appears.